# angular no carga estilos de bootstrap al navegar entre componentes

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap, style

Estoy haciendo un proyecto y tengo un problema, los estilos de mi  pagina están bien cuando la pagina abre por primera vez pero una vez comienzo a navegar entre componentes los estilos bootstrap no cargan bien, creo que es bootstrap porque los css en colores y animaciones si lo hacen y estos estilos solo  vuelven a aparecer al recargar la pagina nuevamente.

No entiendo donde radica el problema puesto que tengo en el **`angular.json`** todo ingresado.

Código **`angular.json`**:

```
  "styles": ["node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css",
    "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/assets/sass/light-bootstrap-dashboard.scss",
    "src/assets/css/demo.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js",
    "node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js"
  ]
},
```

[image: pagina al comenzar a navegar cargando bootstrap]
[image: pagina navegando entre los componentes sin bootstrap]

Answer (score 0):

puede importarlos desde el propio estilo global de Angular, así:

```
/**  style.css  */
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

y en el app.module.ts o punto de entrada para el modelo de datos de su proyecto puede importar el bootstrap así, y en los imports cargar el modulo

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

imports: [
    ...
    NgbModule,
],
```

claro tendría que instalar ng-bootstrap en su proyecto para poder usarlo desde sus componentes en angular.